# Xcode landscape launch image warning when not required

Tags: xcode, image

I am finishing up an app which only runs in portrait mode on the iPad and iPhone. As a result, I don't provide any landscape launch images - I *could* include them, but they would never be seen, so I'd prefer to save the space in my app.

How do I stop XCode trying to auto assign 'Default.png' and 'Default@2x.png' into the landscape images for the iPad? This causes a warning to appear, since these images are for the iPhone and so are the wrong dimensions. Alternatively, a solution to suppress the warning that appears would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control-click on an unwanted iPad launch image in the Summary window and choose Delete. This will remove the reference to the image as a launch image for iPad. Even better, go ahead and include solid black PNG images for the unneeded launch images. They will be compressed by Xcode when it builds your app, so that they will take up virtually no space in the app bundle.

I regard the fact that Xcode automatically creates default launch images for iPhone but not iPad as a bug. I suggest you complain about this behavior at bugreporter.apple.com.

EDIT: Just to be clear, what you want is a minimal set of properly sized images with the following names:

- Default.png
- Default@2x.png
- Default-568h@2x.png
- Default-Portrait~ipad.png
- Default-Landscape~ipad.png
- Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
- Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png

This will prevent Xcode from using e.g. an iPhone launch image in an iPad slot.

Comment: Agree. Note that selecting 'delete' causes the iPhone images to be deleted as well, since removing the reference acts on those as well..

Comment: No physical images are harmed, though. "Delete" here really just deletes the references from the plist file.

Comment: I should have mentioned: I find it useful to keep on hand a set of black default images, properly named, that I can just drop into all new projects if Xcode fails to create them for me.

Comment: Okay. The black images seem like a workaround (I agree this looks like a bug), and although I understand it doesn't harm the physical images, if I try to drop them back onto my iPhone launch images, they get re-assigned to the iPad landscape graphics as well...